# email is not saved in database from Facebook id in php

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, email

My email id is not stored in database. I want to store details of Facebook user in my database. Actually, I have login page in which, user can also login with Facebook but problem is that i get all details except email. I need store the email id also in database.Please help me.any help is appreciate.
here is my code...

```
<?php
require 'facebook/facebook.php';
require 'config/fbconfig.php';
require 'config/functions.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => APP_ID,
    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {

    try {       
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }catch (FacebookApiException $e){

        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
    if(!empty($user_profile )){

        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)
        $username = $user_profile['name'];
        $uid = $user_profile['id'];
        echo $email = $user_profile['email'];
        $user = new User();
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret);
        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

            $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
    }else{

        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
}else{

    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email'));
    header("Location: " . $login_url);
}
```

Comment: where does `INSERT INTO table` come into play?

Comment: I had the same problem a few months ago. Some facebook users had't entered a mail address in their account, because they have used their mobile phone number for registering on facebook.

Comment: but i am using my email id which is not number. i registered with email id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below line :

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

with the following code:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,locale,timezone,email');
```

Comment: thanks Anup GC for your reply but now i am getting only email. i need email, name, oauth_uid. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a suggestion.

Sometimes If user will not give permission access his email id in Facebook. at that time you will not get email id of that user.

So in that scenario you can store user email as 'userid@facebook.com'.

userid is also unique in facebook for every user. So you will get unique email id for every user.

Comment: @ManishaChaudhary actually its userId. I have edited my comment.

Comment: ok. i understood username because username is not unique. yes, i agree with you. user is is unique.